# Powershell script to move file from one location to another then display message box to a different computer on our network

Tags: powershell, automation, messagebox, windows-server

I am having an issue with this Powershell script. I am completely new to powershell. I am trying to automate a specific process. I am attempting to create a script that can take an image, move it to another folder on another drive, then send a message box to a different computer on the domain letting the user know the file transfer has been completed. I was able to get the script to move the file from one location to another the works correctly. I was able to display a message box as well but when I try to add an image to the message box I get the following error below. Also, I have no idea how to send this messagebox to a different computer other than the one the script is running on. Help please.

> Cannot convert argument "icon", with value:
> "C:\Users\austin.holmes\Downloads\botpic.jpg", for "Show" to type
> "System.Windows.MessageBoxImage": "Cannot convert value
> "C:\Users\austin.holmes\Downloads\botpic.jpg" to type
> "System.Windows.MessageBoxImage".  Error: "Unable to match the
> identifier name C:\Users\austin.holmes\Downloads\botpic.jpg  to a
> valid enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names
> and try  again: None, Hand, Error, Stop, Question, Exclamation,
> Warning, Asterisk, Information"" At line:9 char:1+
> [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

CODE:

```
$_SourcePath = "C:\dummy.txt"
$_DestinationPath = "D:\"
Copy-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath
$msgButton = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
$msgTitle = “Little Sis Sync Agent Bot!”
$msgbody = “Little Sis Sync Agent files have been moved. Thank me later. :]”
$msgImage = 'C:\Users\austin.holmes\Downloads\botpic.jpg'
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)
```

I tried the Invoke-Command and I get the follwing error

```
$_SourcePath = "C:\Users\austin.holmes\Desktop\dummy.txt"
$_DestinationPath = "C:\"
Copy-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath
Invoke-Command -ComputerName AHC-L80316-AH -ScriptBlock{
$msgButton = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::'OK'
$msgTitle = “Little Sis Sync Agent Bot!”
$msgbody = “Little Sis Sync Agent files have been moved!”
$msgImage = 'Warning'
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)}
```

> [AHC-L80316-AH] Connecting to remote server AHC-L80316-AH failed with
> the following  error message : The client cannot connect to the
> destination specified in the request.  Verify that the service on the
> destination is running and is accepting requests.  Consult the logs
> and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
> destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the
> WinRM service, run  the following command on the destination to
> analyze and configure the WinRM service:  "winrm quickconfig". For
> more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help  topic.

Comment: You are basically asking 2 or 3 different things here. Also, displaying a messasge box on *another* computer is really possible that easily, and not a reasonable thing to do imho. Maybe go into more detail what you're trying to achieve, and we can help you with the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: I agree with @marsze sending message boxes is not a straight forward process and functionality that facilitated this was disabled a while back. From your explanation I think this should be broken into 2 components, 1 script your side that is executed when you want to push the file and another script on the other PC with a file system watcher on the directory that you will be pushing to, the recipient side could then create a message box when a folder has changed, and you can add additional logic so that it obly appears when file has been made by X user.

Comment: Ok so basically I log into a different server via Remote Desktop Connection and I have to move files from one drive to the next. On that server, I planned on scheduling a powershell script that will move the file from one folder to  another but I want to be notified on the computer im using without having to be logged in via remote desktop connection so I figured a message box saying the files were transfered would work. If this wont work Ill just schedule it on the server and log in and check to see if the files were moved but that kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: AND OF COURSE MY QUESTION GETS CLOSED BY STACK OVERFLOW THANKS FOR HELPING STACK ALWAYS A PLEASURE.

Answer (score 0):

In a MessageBox you can only display one of the available icons in the MessageBoxImage-enumerator. As the errormessage says, use None, Hand, Error, Stop, Question, Exclamation, Warning, Asterisk or Information

To show your own images, you will have to created a separate form.

To run code on a remote computer (in this case your own), use Invoke-Command with computername and scriptblock as parameters. Take a lock at The following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7

Comment: I tried Invoke-Command and I pointed the message to be sent to my computer and I got the following error:  [AHC-L80316-AH] Connecting to remote server AHC-L80316-AH failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. 
Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.

Comment: Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the 
destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run 
the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: 
"winrm quickconfig".

Comment: Yeah sorry, I remember now that you can't Invoke-Command on computer that have an active remote connection (atleast from what I can tell). Sorry about that. But if you have Win10 you can use BurntToast. Easy module for toastmessages.